# How To Hide Span on click of TextBox in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what I need

- i need when user click on textbox  error messge are hidden or removed.

html code

```
  <div class="6u pdt">

<input class="text orgsmall" type="text" name="designation" id ="designation" placeholder="Designation" value="" onfocus="$(this).parent().find('.name').text('');">
 <span class="name" style="color:red"></span>
</div>
```

js

```
          <script>
            var designation=$("#designation").val();

            var email=$("#email").val();

            var company=$("#company").val();

            var website=$("#website").val();

            var country_name=$("#country_name").val();

            var city_name=$("#city_name").val();
            var mobile_code=$("#mobile_code").val();

            var description=$("#description").val();


                if(name =='Enter Your Name' || designation =='Designation' || company=='Company' || website=='Website' || country_name=='Country' || city_name=='City' || email=='Email' || mobile_code=='Mobile' || description=='Your Message....')
                {
                    $(".name").text("Please Enter values").show();
                    return false;

                }
```

Debug

- i want like when user submit form if fields are empty form not submitted .
- error message are shown .
- then lastly when click on textbox error message are removed.
- i just need to access span elemnt through focus on textbox.
- In IE8 Placeholder is TREATED as Textbox.
- $(this).parent().find('.name').text('');//returns []
- $(this).parent();
  -undefined;
- $('.name').text(''); // only works .

Comment: plz explain in detail..

Comment: try this $(this).closest('.name').hide()

Comment: @jQuery `.name` is not `.closest()` element, it is `.next()` element.

Comment: $(this).next('.name').hide(); //returns []

Comment: problem is in ie 8 otherwise i could use juqery statement

Comment: @Jai hope this will work ? $(this).next('span.name').hide();

Comment: @user3785613 the thing you are doing is not a good way, try to be more unobtrusive instead of inline.

Comment: $(this).next('span.name').hide() //[] empty

Answer (score 1):

> **Few change in html**

```
<input class="text orgsmall" type="text" name="designation" id ="designation" placeholder="Designation" value="" onfocus="$(this).parent().find('.name').hide();">
<span class="name" style="color:red">Error</span>
```

> **And few in js**

```
$("button").on("click",function(){
           var designation=$("#designation").val();
           alert(designation);
            if(designation =="")
            {
                $(".name").text("Please Enter values").show();
            }
 });
```

I have editted my fiddle according to your requirement.Have a look

[**Try out this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s5y88qmy/16/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('input').click(function(){
$(this).parent().find('.name').text('');// this will `remove` the text from `innerHTML` if you only want to `hide` use `hide()`.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="text orgsmall" type="text" name="designation" id ="designation" placeholder="Designation" value="">
 <span class="name" style="color:red">remove me</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should be using `.hide()`

**Working Code Snippet:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="6u pdt">
  <input class="text orgsmall" type="text" name="designation" id ="designation" placeholder="Designation" value="" onfocus="$(this).parent().find('.name').hide();">
  <span class="name" style="color:red">Span</span>
</div>
```

Learn more: [`.hide()` | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(this).closest('.name').addClass('hide')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
$('#designation').click(function () {
   $(this).next().text(''); 
});
```